# Coloring random points in an annulus

Tags: color, random

I have found the following random generator to generate points in an annulus in stackoverflow [on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13064912/generate-a-uniformly-random-point-within-an-annulus-ring)

```
f[] := Block[{u, t, r}, u = Random[] + Random[];
r1 = 1; r2 = 0.3;
t = Random[] 2 Pi;
r = If[u > 1, 2 - u, u];
r = If[r < r2, r2 + r*((R1 - R2)/R2), r];
{r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}]

ListPlot[Table[f[], {10000}], AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

Now I would like to for instance color red when x*y positive or blue when x*y is negative. I have tried tweaking around with ColorFun but that gives me very beautiful images, but nothing what I actually want.
What is the best method to approach this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
R1 = 2;
R2 = 3;
t = Table[f[], {10000}];
vc = If[Times @@ # <= 0, Blue, Red] & /@ t;
```

**Use `Graphics` with `VertexColors`:**

```
Graphics[Point[t, VertexColors -> vc], Axes -> True, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

**Split the data based on `Sign [x y]` and use `PlotStyle`:**

```
t2 = Pick[t, Sign[Times @@@ t], #] & /@ {1, -1};
ListPlot[t2, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

or

```
t3 = GatherBy[t, Sign[Times @@ #] &];
ListPlot[t3, AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

**Post-process `ListPlot` output to re-color the points:**

```
ListPlot[t, AspectRatio -> Automatic]  /. 
     Point[x : {__}] :> ({If[ Times @@ # <= 0, Red, Blue], Point@#} & /@ x)
```

or

```
ListPlot[t, AspectRatio -> Automatic]  /.  Point[x_] :> Point[x, VertexColors -> vc]
```

to get

[image]

**Update: Following ybeltukov's lead ...**

**Using `TransformedDistribution` and `RandomVariate` to generate random points in an annulus**

```
ClearAll[annulusDist];
annulusDist[r1_, r2_, t1_: 0, t2_: 2 Pi] := 
  TransformedDistribution[Sqrt@v {Cos[u], Sin[u]},
   {u \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{t1, t2}], 
    v \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{r1^2, r2^2}]}];

pts1 = RandomVariate[annulusDist[1, 2], 2000000];
Histogram3D[pts1, 50, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

```
pts2 = RandomVariate[annulusDist[1, 2, Pi/4, 7 Pi/4], 5000];

ListPlot[Pick[pts2, Sign[Times @@@ pts2], #] & /@ {1, -1}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1,  PlotRange -> {{-Pi, Pi}, {-Pi, Pi}}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue}]
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any advantage (i.e., speed) in using any of those three?

Comment: @Jonas, based on limited tests, the method based on `Pick` seems to be faster than the other two.

Comment: @Jonas, using `Graphics` and `VertexColors` seems to be faster than all the others posted so far.

Comment: @JonasTeuwen Replacing `vc` with the following will give great kernel speed: `(vc = Compile[{{p, _Real, 2}}, If[# > 0, {1., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 1.}] & /@ (#[[1]] #[[2]] &@ Transpose@p)] @ pts`.  But the time spent rendering in the front end is significant, and it pretty much washes out the advantage.  If you have many different colors, then `VertexColors` is the way to go.  But the `ListPlot` code above divides the points into two sets and just uses a color two times in the output; `VertexColors` uses a color 10000 times.

Comment: It does work well, but if I replace the condition for the check with another one it fails if there are no such points (for instance when I shift the annulus in the first kwadrant. Is there an easy way to resolve this?

Comment: @Jonas, can you give a specific example of that case?

Comment: @kguler: Yes, when I set `randomInAnnulus[R1_, R2_, cb_: 0, n_: 100] := 
  Transpose@{# Cos@#2 + cb, # Sin@#2 + cb} &[
   Sqrt@RandomReal[{R1, R2}^2, n], RandomReal[2 \[Pi], n]];`
and I pick cb so large that x*y > 0 for all points I get an error.

Comment: @Jonas, I see. When `x y <0` or `x y >0` for all points in the data set, one of the two lists is `{}` and `ListPlot` does not like such input.  If you change the first argument of `ListPlot` to `Pick[pts2, Sign[Times @@@ pts2], #] & /@ {1, -1} /. {} -> Sequence[]`, it works fine.

Answer (score 8):

You already receive great answers concerning the colors, but your random generator confuses me. It is not uniform in the annulus and it's not efficient. I propose the following short and fast generator

```
randomInAnnulus[R1_, R2_, n_] := 
  Transpose@{# Cos@#2, # Sin@#2} &[Sqrt@RandomReal[{R1, R2}^2, n], RandomReal[2 π, n]];

pts = randomInAnnulus[1, 2, 20000000];

Histogram3D[pts, 50]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Graphics[{If[Times @@ # > 0, Red, Blue], Point[#]} & /@ A]
```

which produces this:

[image]

I used `R1 = 1.0; R2 = 0.5;` as the constants. `A` is the list of random points.

This plotting method is pretty slow; unfortunately `ListPlot` requires `Joined -> True` for `ColorFunction` to be applied, and for random points it just looks like a mess.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed it is quite slow. Do you have any ideas how to do it faster?

Comment: @JonasTeuwen: One possible way to make it faster is to use kguler's answer based on `Pick`, which basically separates your list into two, and then colors the two separate lists a different color using `PlotStyle`. I'm not sure why it's slow, but it appears to be tied to the frontend: if you suppress visual output using `;`, it executes immediately, so it's probably not the kernel's fault, but rather the frontend's fault.